# Best practice to add static content to be served by NGINX ?

Tags: post, nginx, nginx-location

I have found extensive documentation on how to serve static content with NGINX but I haven't found a good source of information with best practices to have the content (files in the file system) added.
Is POSTing acceptable? or NGNIX by design delegates the actual population of content to another process?

Comment: There are some third party modules, but in general nginx has nothing to do with where files come from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx is best as a proxy server. You could add functionality to do much more in nginx, including posting files, with [openresty](https://openresty.org/).

Generally, send the post request to another process to handle it, such as nodejs.

If I misunderstood, and you just want to get your local files into the server directories that nginx is using, check out [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)